# gtk+ native ms windows application - how do I redistribute the gtk libraries with my app?

Tags: windows, gtk, mingw

I've compile my helloworld gtk+ application using MinGW for Native MS Windows.  The instructions I followed were [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799904/how-to-compile-gtk-application-for-native-windows-and-not-for-x-windows).

If I run the helloworld.exe application from the same command window that I built the application, it works fine.

However, I would like to distribute the gtk+ libraries with my app, so I have downloaded and extracted all of the runtimes from http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php.

I have also copied my helloworld.exe application to the bin folder with the gtk runtime files.

When I attempt to run my application in a new command prompt, I get the following error:

[image: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)]

My machine is 64 bit, but I downloaded the 32 bit runtime for gtk.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to extract the gtk+ [all-in-one-bundle](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip) to a clean folder, and copy the application to the extracted bin folder.

The extracted all-in-one-bundle can then be zipped with the included application and distributed as a zip or tar file.